# Python codecs encoding not working

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this code

```
import collections
import csv
import sys
import codecs
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
import xml.dom.minidom

String = collections.namedtuple("String", ["tag", "text"])

def read_translations(filename): #Reads a csv file with rows made up of 2 columns: the string tag, and the translated tag
    with codecs.open(filename, "r", encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
        result = [String(tag=row[0], text=row[1]) for row in csv_reader]
    return result
```

The CSV file I'm reading contains Brazilian portuguese characters. When I try to run this, I get an error:

```
'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x88 in position 21: invalid start byte
```

I'm using Python 2.7. As you can see, I'm encoding with codecs, but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps your file is not saved as UTF-8?

Comment: Try and change `encoding='utf-8'` to `encoding='cp1252'`.  We can't tell much without seeing the data.

Comment: What those guys said. Windows doesn't use UTF-8 unless you force it to; any random file that you open will most likely be encoded with the current Windows code page. You can use `encoding='mbcs'` to get that without knowing specifically what it is.

Comment: Forgot to add that I'm using a Mac on this. I've opened the files using Sublime and Saved with encoding UTF-8. I tried cp1252 but it returns this error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 31: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: You need to find out which encoding was used to generate the file. If you open the file in an editor do you see the proper characters?

Comment: Are you sure it is not latin-1?

Answer (score -1):

The idea of this line:

```
with codecs.open(filename, "r", encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
```

is to say "This file was saved as utf-8. Please make appropriate conversions when reading from it."

That works fine if the file was actually saved as utf-8. If some other encoding was used, then it is bad.

**What then?**

Determine which encoding was used. Assuming the information cannot be obtained from the software which created the file - guess.

Open the file normally and print each line:

```
with open(filename, 'rt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print repr(line)
```

Then look for a character which is not ASCII, e.g. ñ - this letter will be printed as some code, e.g.:

```
'espa\xc3\xb1ol'
```

Above, ñ is represented as `\xc3\xb1`, because that is the utf-8 sequence for it.

Now, you can check what various encodings would give and see which is right:

```
>>> ntilde = u'\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER N WITH TILDE}'
>>> 
>>> print repr(ntilde.encode('utf-8'))
'\xc3\xb1'
>>> print repr(ntilde.encode('windows-1252'))
'\xf1'
>>> print repr(ntilde.encode('iso-8859-1'))
'\xf1'
>>> print repr(ntilde.encode('macroman'))
'\x96'
```

Or print all of them:

```
for c in encodings.aliases.aliases:
    try:
        encoded = ntilde.encode(c)
        print c, repr(encoded)
    except:
        pass
```

Then, when you have guessed which encoding it is, use that, e.g.:

```
with codecs.open(filename, "r", encoding='iso-8859-1') as csvfile:
```